# How to add a Silverlight Control to the Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 Toolbox?

Tags: silverlight

I'm able to add WinForms controls programmatically but not with Silverlight Controls. How to add a Silverlight Control to the Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 Toolbox? I have read/tried almost suggested tools and solutions available on stackoverflow.com but no articles mention about Silverlight Control.

Answer (score 0):

Just referencing the assembly (DLL) that defines the Silverlight control you want will make it appear in the toolbox.
Right-click your project and select Add references... then select the assembly.